# Get content of tag and insert as value to property of same tag

Tags: javascript, php

Suppose you have an  tag with some content:

```
<a title="">Action</a>
```

and you'd like to automatically and dynamically get the content to replace the title

```
<a title="Action">Action</a>
```

Using either JS or PHP.

Can this be done?

Comment: Yes, it's very simple with Javascript. Have you attempted anything?

Comment: If you don't know where to start then look at: [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var),[`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName),[`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent), [`HTMLElement.title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.title) and a good place to play is [`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pure JS:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); //get elements and store in var
for ( var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++ ) {  // loop through the elements
    elems[i].setAttribute('title',elems[i].textContent);  // set title attribute to text
}
```

I suggest that in the future you at least try something on your own before you ask a question